# How can I normalize the angle to postive x-axis

Tags: javascript, math, svg, geometry

I need to find the normalized angle in +ve x-axis. Its in 2D.
I believe positive x-axis should fall in between 0-90 degrees.

Can someone help me with that.I get 180 degrees , instead of 0 degrees.

Please have a look at below code snippet:

```js
  private getAngleOfSegment(indexStart: number, indexEnd: number) {
    //Finding angle of each segment
    //radians= math.atan2(dy, dx) ; angle = radians * (180/pi)
    let A, B: ICoordinate;
    A = this.polygon.coordinates[indexStart];
    B = this.polygon.coordinates[indexEnd];
    let angle = Math.atan2(B.y - A.y, B.x - A.x) * (180 / Math.PI);
    if (angle < 0) {
      console.log(angle);
      angle += 180;
    } else if (angle > 90) {
      angle = 180 - angle;
    }
    return angle;
  }
```

Help and suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to get for directions (possible results of atan2 in degrees): 0, 45, 90, 135, 180, -45, -90, -135 ?

Comment: I want all postive.

Comment: `atan2` returns radians, you've to add __`2*PI`__ to the negative values, and then decrease the angle by PI / 2 to get the positive normal.

Comment: Please make correspondence for my input values and desired output values. And... what is **real** problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have coordinates [-20, -20],
        [-20, 20],
        [-40, 0],
        [-40, 20],
        [-40, 40],
        [-20, 80],
        [20, 80],
        [40, 40],
        [80, 20],
        [80, -20] , want their angles to be in positive x-axis.

Comment: would  radians * (180 / Math.PI) not help @Teemu

Comment: There is no such term "angles to be in positive x-axis". Perhaps range -90..+90?

Comment: Please recheck the comment. That would be only a rad to deg conversion, what you need is to add a full circle to negative radians.